# push/pop current directory?

Tags: linux, bash

With bash is there a way to push and pop the current working directory? I tried writing `bash;cd dir; ./dostuff;exit;` but the current directory is now `dir`.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

There is `pushd` and `popd`

> Bash will keep a history of the directories you visit, you just have to ask.
>   Bash stores the history in a stack and uses the commands pushd
>   and popd to manage the stack.

[More to read](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/pushd_and_popd.shtml)

Example:

```
$ pwd; pushd /tmp; pwd; popd; pwd
/home/me
/tmp ~
/tmp
~
/home/me
```

Comment: Excerpt from the link`pushd Saves the current directory on the top of the directory stack and then cd to dir. With no arguments, pushd  exchanges the top two directories.`

Answer (score 36):

Calling `bash` starts a new subshell, which has its own input; none of the other commands will run until it exits. Surrounding the commands to be run with parens will also start a new subshell, but it will run the commands within it.

```
( cd dir ; ./dostuff )
```

Answer (score 15):

If you don't need multiple levels of directory history, you can also do:

```
cd foo
# do your stuff in foo
cd -
```

Compared to `pushd`/`popd`, this has the disadvantage that if `cd foo` fails, you end up in the wrong directory with `cd -`.

(Probably `cd -` is more handy outside scripts. "Let's go back where I just was.")

Comment: is it posix compatible? could not quickly find the answer, probably someone knows right away

Comment: UPD. found, yes, compatible, this is actually `cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd`. https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/cd/

Answer (score 7):

I use alias for keeping track of my directory changes so to 'cd' somewhere I can just go back to where I was using 'cd.', or go back two using 'cd..', etc.;

```
alias pushdd="pushd \$PWD > /dev/null"
alias cd='pushdd;cd'
alias ssh='ssh -A'
alias soc='source ~/.bashrc'
#below to go back to a previous directory (or more)
alias popdd='popd >/dev/null'
alias cd.='popdd'
alias cd..='popdd;popdd'
alias cd...='popdd;popdd;popdd'
alias cd....='popdd;popdd;popdd;popdd'
#below to remove directories from the stack only (do not 'cd' anywhere)
alias .cd='popd -n +0'
alias ..cd='popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0;popd -n +0'
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what this code does?

Comment: That's clever. I have aliases around my pushd and popd to do some things I like. I use the directory stack all the time. I hate watching people cd somewhere and then scroll back looking for the previous directory to cut and paste. I can't do most of my work in my home directory because of quotas, so i have to use pooled storage on the network.

Comment: Is the alias `..cd` robust enough? it looks like it only remove the last 10 items from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

`pushd` add on to a directory stack

`popd` remove off of a directory stack

`dirs` view directory stack

`dirs -p` "display directory entries one per line"

`dirs -c` "clear the directory stack"